# Bernoulli equation $xy'-(1+x)y=xy^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm new Bernoulli, the question ask to solve the following

> $$xy'-(1+x)y=xy^2$$

Here are my works

$$y'-(\frac{1}{x}+1)y=y^2$$

since $n=2$, set $z=y^{1-2}=y^-1$

$$\frac{dz}{dx}-(1-2)(\frac{1}{x}+1)z=(1-2)1$$

$$\frac{dz}{dx}+(\frac{1}{x}+1)z=-1$$

the integrating factor, I = $e^{\frac{1}{x}+1}=xe^x$

$$\rightarrow z=\frac{c}{xe^x} + \frac{1}{xe^x}\int{xe^x}(-1)dx$$

$$ z=\frac{c}{xe^x} - \frac{1}{xe^x}\int{xe^x}dx$$

since $\int{xe^x}dx = xe^x - e^x$

$$ z=\frac{c}{xe^x} - \frac{1}{xe^x}(xe^x - e^x)$$

$$ z=\frac{c}{xe^x} - 1 + \frac{1}{x}$$

then

$$\rightarrow  y=\frac{1}{\frac{c}{xe^x} - 1 + \frac{1}{x}}$$

Have I miscalculate anything, can someone verify my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well:
$$y=(\dfrac{c}{xe^x}-1+\dfrac1x)^{-1}\implies y'=(\dfrac{1}{x^2}+c\dfrac{x+1}{x^2e^x})(\dfrac{c}{xe^x}-1+\dfrac1x)^{-2}$$
So:
$$xy'-(1+x)y=(\dfrac{1}{x}+c\dfrac{x+1}{xe^x})(\dfrac{c}{xe^x}-1+\dfrac1x)^{-2}-(1+x)(\dfrac{c}{xe^x}-1+\dfrac1x)^{-1}$$
Which Wolfram Alpha simplifies to:
$$xy'-(1+x)y=\dfrac{e^{2x}x^3}{(-c-e^x+e^xx)^2}$$
And:
$$xy^2=x(\dfrac{c}{xe^x}-1+\dfrac1x)^{-2}$$
Which WolframAlpha simplifies to:
$$xy^2=\dfrac{e^{2x}x^3}{(-c-e^x+e^xx)^2}$$
So you are correct.